# How do you make a button dependable on another button to load a specific link in android? java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a button on my activity dependable on a specific Toggle button being clicked to load a WebView on another actvity. How do I do this? I am a beginner, so concrete examples will help. I'm currently using the onCheckedChanged method. Do I need a separate onClick method and listener for the main button? I also keep getting an error on my view parameter and I don't know why. Below is what I have so far:

```
redToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

@Override      
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean select) {

CompoundButton view = null; 

if (view.getId() == R.id.redToggle) {
       webResultsView.loadUrl(url1);
```

Comment: `if(redToggle.isChecked()){  // Do your stuff }`.

Comment: This would be under the onCheckedChanged method right?

Comment: NO . inside Button Click .